# Error in Laravel Handler error context with Auth

Tags: php, laravel, exception, php-7, laravel-5.5

After some investigation, here is what I found:

When an user make a request with a wrong Bearer to our API an **OAuthServerException** is thrown and the **report** method of the **Handler** class is called to looking for a context to add to the report information. During the **context** method, the **Auth** facade is called and this is where it double fail and a brut 503 error is called.

To hide the problem I've added OAuthServerException::class to the $dontreport property, but this doesn't solve the problem, it shouldn't be hidden...

Could you please help me figure out why the Auth facade failed when an OAuthServerException is thrown ?

**Edit**: To add some "context", I've found this bug report and the PR associated that look like my problem but doesn't talk about the Auth facade... 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21041 but maybe it's linked.

**Edit2**: The User extends Auth\User of Laravel as expected:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use ModelTrait, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /* some methods */
}
```

**Edit3**: added the Handler class

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\HttpException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
        OAuthServerException::class // This is just a temporary fix 
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Exception $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
            return response()->json(
                ['error' => $exception->getMessage()],
                $exception->getCode()
            );
        }
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
            ];
            $response['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
            if (get_class($exception) == 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException') {
                $response['rules'] = $exception->validator->errors();
            }
            if (config('app.debug')) {
                // Add the exception class name, message and stack trace to response
                $response['exception'] = get_class($exception); // Reflection might be better here

                $response['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
            }
            // Default response of 400
            $status = 400;
            // If this exception is an instance of HttpException
            if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
                // Grab the HTTP status code from the Exception
                $status = $exception->getStatusCode();
            }
            // Return a JSON response with the response array and status code
            return response()->json($response, $status);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
}
```

And those two function come from Laravel\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler (the parent of my Handler class) and the 503 occurs in the context method, when calling **Auth**.

```
/**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->shouldntReport($e)) {
            return;
        }

        if (method_exists($e, 'report')) {
            return $e->report();
        }

        try {
            $logger = $this->container->make(LoggerInterface::class);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw $e; // throw the original exception
        }
        $logger->error(
            $e->getMessage(),
            array_merge($this->context(), ['exception' => $e]
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get the default context variables for logging.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function context()
    {

        try {
            return array_filter([
                'userId' => Auth::id(),
                'email' => Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->email : null,
            ]);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might need to add some snippets of code to help see exactly what is going on. I assume its Passport you are using. What does your middleware look like? Any other config different from the norm?

Comment: @Paul the Handler class is the one in Laravel directly out of the box and it's the same for Passport...

Comment: We need snippets to help you @Paul

Comment: @PaulSantos I've added the Handler classes but I don't really know what code snippet to provide. The Middleware, it's also the one from Laravel Passport, nothing new.

Comment: @Roadirsh, just by any chance, did you update your config/auth.php to use the correct namespace of your model?

Comment: @PaulSantos yes  https://imgur.com/PpLjNId

Comment: Do you have any middleware in this route?

Comment: @SantoshAchari just auth:api from Laravel Passport, but I've found out that this is a known issue of Laravel Passport, https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/507 or https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/440 ... Until it's fixed with a PR, I don't think we can make something about it...

Comment: Okay. Just as an FYI, middlewares are handled before the try catch you are using. Hence the crash.

Comment: @SantoshAchari Yes, and the middleware auth:api is the one that failed, it is use to check the Bearer token of an user, when the token is invalid it throw an execption that is then catch by the Exception Handler, and reported, and during the report, the app try to get the context and it failed hard.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, when reporting the exception the `Auth::` methods are called, which in turn causes another exception of the same type to be thrown.

If you don't want to `dontReport` this exception you could instead override the `context` method and have it return just `[]`.

However, it may indeed make sense not to report the OAuthServerException. See how the base exception handler does not report `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` or `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`. This would be another auth-related exception that you are not reporting.

Comment: Yes but why is this exception not catched by the Throwable class ? That is the purpose of it, to return an empty array if Auth fail. I should not have to need to override it...

Comment: @Roadirsh I think it is caught [earlier in the process](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3a92f48445268c3a828d04e3f2bba91645692721/src/Http/Controllers/HandlesOAuthErrors.php#L29), that's why the error you see is not an exception thrown, instead it's a loop (`OAuthServerException -> report -> context -> OAuthServerException ->  report...`)

Comment: It's first catched [in the token guard](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/3a92f48445268c3a828d04e3f2bba91645692721/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php#L140)  but why does Auth fail. When I call Auth::id() not authenticated it should just return null, not an exception. Same for Auth::check(). The 503 error appears when the Auth facade is instanciated. For me it's not the same exception, so no loop...

Comment: @Roadirsh oh ok, I will try to reproduce this and get back to you later